# C# #define keyword available project wide

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Declare preprocesor symbol (like DEBUG) globaly for whole project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692595/c-declare-preprocesor-symbol-like-debug-globaly-for-whole-project)

Can I set up a `#NOTEMBEDDED` definition in a project so that when I'm debugging and I hit a

```
#if NOTEMBEDDED

#endif
```

in various source files it will acknowledge it and fall into the if statement?

Answer (score 3):

Add it to the project settings, right-click on the project, select Properties, under the Build tab there's a "Conditional compilation symbols".

You enter your conditional there.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Build tab in Project Properties and add it to the `Conditional compilation symbols` box.

Comment: That highlights the code in the if statement so it looks ok however its not falling inside the if statement