# How to notice if the app is being debugged

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8

I just program a game in Windows Phone 8 with an advertising, but the advertisement only works when the Phone isn't in Debug mode. Is there a possibility to notice if the app is being debugged or not?

I tried it so, but it don't works.

```
bool b1 = false;
#if DEBUG
            b1 = true;            
#endif
            if (!b1)
            {
                //no Debugging
            }
```

Comment: Did you define DEBUG symbol when you compiled your app?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692595/c-declare-preprocesor-symbol-like-debug-globaly-for-whole-project). Add DEBUG symbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The use of a preprocessor define will only tell you that you are running a debug version of the app. If you want to check that you are actively debugging, use this:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
  //Debug stuff
}
```